# Update openssl in debian squeeze

Tags: debian, openssl

There is this [CVE-2014-0224](http://www.openssl.org/news/secadv_20140605.txt) bug in openssl so I would like to update my affected

```
# openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
```

But there is [no update for squeeze](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2014-0224). I read the it is already [fixed in squeeze-LTS](http://www.heise.de/security/news/foren/S-squeeze-lts-schon-gefixt/forum-280802/msg-25328529/read/). What I am supposed to do? Will there be an fix for squeeze and I just need to wait?

Should I install an openssl update manually? How? I tried to install openssl-0.9.8za and openssl-1.0.1h with `wget, ./config, make, make install` but `openssl version` is still that same. I also tried [config parameters](http://mariobrandt.de/archives/linux/upgrading-openssl-on-debian-6-squeeze-or-ubuntu-8-04-hardy-456/) but with this build fails.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

squeeze is not supported anymore. see [Debian Security Announcement](https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2938) for the reasons.

If you want to have security updates you need to change your sources.list

You even qoute the post where it stands what you need to enter:

> cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep lts
>
> deb http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
>
> deb-src http://ftp2.de.debian.org/debian squeeze-lts main contrib non-free

This only works for x86 and x64

So you **have to do** following (qouting the wiki):

for binary packages add this line:

```
deb http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

for source packages add this line:

```
deb-src http://http.debian.net/debian/ squeeze-lts main contrib non-free
```

Source: [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/LTS/Using)

However the lts support has also run out.

> Information for users
>
> Support for Squeeze LTS will end five years after the release of Squeeze, i.e. until the 6th of February 2016.

Source : [Debian Security Information](https://www.debian.org/security/2014/dsa-2938)